# WPF MVVM Directly accessing object list from ViewModelClass

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My question may sound silly but I really don't know how to do it because it gives me an error. So I have a class with objects inside ObservableCollection:

```cs
public class UIElementList
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChangingUIElements> ElementList { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to directly access this class from my ViewModel class like this:

```cs
private UIElementList uIElementList = new UIElementList();

public UIElementList UIElementList
{
    get => uIElementList.ElementList;
}
```

but something terribly wrong, because compiler gives me an error:
**Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<PartialResultOperation.Model.ChangingUIElements>' to 'PartialResultOperation.Model.UIElementList'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
private UIElementList uIElementList = new UIElementList();
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ChangingUIElements> UIElementList2
{
    get => uIElementList.ElementList;
}

public class UIElementList
{
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ChangingUIElements> ElementList { get; set; }
}
```

Problem:

```
public UIElementList UIElementList
{
    get => uIElementList.ElementList
}
```

Here you try to return an `UIElementList`, but the `uIElementList.ElementList` is an ObservableCollection. Therefore this can't work.

Also your property name has the same name as your class. Please avoid this (so instead of `UIElementList UIElementList` write any other property name).

or you could also use a method:

```
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ChangingUIElements> GetUIElementList()
{
    return uIElementList.ElementList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm! :)